# jdbc driver to sqlite does not work in java

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I use jdbc driver connect to sqlite database which is produced by sqlite manager. I use the following one, it works well,

```
     Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C://Users//13149//Desktop//SqliteDB0.sqlite");
```

When I replace the above one by the following one,

```
    Connection conn =DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:localhost:3306//Database//SqliteDB0.sqlite");      (*)
```

the first run, it stops there, nothing happen. But when I again, it always gives following error messages:

```
    java.sql.SQLException: path to 'localhost:3306//Database//SqliteDB0.sqlite': 'C:\Users\13149\Documents\NetBeansProjects\SqliteOpenDB\localhost:3306' does not exist
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.open(CoreConnection.java:192)
at org.sqlite.core.CoreConnection.<init>(CoreConnection.java:76)
at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Connection.<init>(JDBC3Connection.java:24)
at org.sqlite.jdbc4.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:23)
at org.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.<init>(SQLiteConnection.java:45)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.createConnection(JDBC.java:114)
at org.sqlite.JDBC.connect(JDBC.java:88)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:270)
at sqliteopendb.SqliteOpenDB.main(SqliteOpenDB.java:30)
```

Here SqliteOpenDB.java:30 is (*) sentence. Anyone can help me? Thanks.

Comment: Looks like the database does not exists

Comment: Does the database exist on your localhost port 3306 ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the driver does not support networked SQLite databases because it's interpreting localhost:3306 as a relative path to a file in your working directory. The [driver documentation](https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) doesn't say anything about supporting a feature like that. Indeed [I've never seen a SQLite that listens on the network](https://www.sqlite.org/serverless.html). What are you trying to do?